# Method not running when initiated in another class

Tags: java, user-interface

so I have a few classes but the two in question are my Character class and Gui class

In my Character class I have (essentially)

```
public class Character implements Serializable
{
    Gui gui = new Gui();


public Character(String name,int row,int col,int bounds){
    this.name = name;
    this.row = row;
    this.col = col;
    this.bounds = bounds;
}

    public String toString()
    {       
        gui.labels(row, col);
        return (name + " at (" + row + "," + col + ")\t");        
    }
}
```

And then in my Gui class I have this

```
public void labels(int x, int y)
    {
        label[0][0] = label00;
        label[0][1] = label01;
        label[0][2] = label02;
        label[0][3] = label03;
        label[1][0] = label10;
        label[1][1] = label11;
        label[1][2] = label12;
        label[1][3] = label13;
        label[2][0] = label20;
        label[2][1] = label21;
        label[2][2] = label22;
        label[2][3] = label23;
        label[3][0] = label30;
        label[3][1] = label31;
        label[3][2] = label32;
        label[3][3] = label33;



            JLabel jLabel = label[x][y];            
            jLabel.setText("0");
            jLabel.setText("Test");

    }
```

And what is meant to happen is the toString function is meant to send the Col and Row values to the labels function in the Gui and then the Gui sets the label accordingly

However it just doesn't do anything and I don't know why, but if I make a test button on the Gui and then make it call the function labels like this for example

```
        JButton settingsButton = new JButton("Settings");
        settingsButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                labels(3, 1);
            }
        });
```

It works perfectly fine, am I missing something here? I can't quite understand why this isn't working

Comment: Side effects in `toString` is a bad idea, just don't...

Comment: Sorry forgot to remove that, was testing something before it my bad

Comment: You change the label[x][y] text to "Test" when you perform toString in Character. But... when do you call toString?